# Column 'id' not found. SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

i'm trying to execute this query inside the spring boot repository class , but console shows the error ' `column id not found` ' also the postman shows:

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "could not execute query; SQL [SELECT etablissement.etab_name , app_user.creatdate_time FROM etablissement JOIN app_user WHERE year(app_user.creatdate_time)= ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query",
```

**QUERY REPOSITORY**

```java
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT etablissement.etab_name , app_user.creatdate_time FROM etablissement JOIN app_user WHERE year(app_user.creatdate_time)= :year")
public List<User> findALLUserByyear(@Param("year") String year);
```

**CONTROLLER**

```java
@GetMapping(value="/etablissementAlls/{year}")
public EtablissementDto EtabDTOALL(@PathVariable String year) {
    EtablissementDto a = new EtablissementDto();
    
    a.setUsers(userRepository.findALLUserByyear(year));
            
    return a;
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
2021-05-05 11:14:17.600  WARN 5240 --- [nio-8020-exec-2] org.club.config.JwtRequestFilter         : JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String
2021-05-05 11:14:17.604  WARN 5240 --- [nio-8020-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2021-05-05 11:14:17.604 ERROR 5240 --- [nio-8020-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
2021-05-05 11:14:17.606 ERROR 5240 --- [nio-8020-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT etablissement.etab_name , app_user.creatdate_time FROM etablissement JOIN app_user WHERE year(app_user.creatdate_time)= ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1080) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
```

**NOTE**

*I tested this query in MYSQL PHPmyAdmin, and it works fine*

**USER ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")

    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "is_active")
        private boolean active;    
        @JsonIgnore 
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_etablissement", joinColumns
                = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "etablissement_id",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private List<Etablissement> etablissements;
```

Comment: Stack trace, please ?

Comment: @The Head , it's added

Comment: Do you have an ID field in app_user, etablissement? If not, create one, if you doand it differs from "id", you may have to annotate it

Comment: Attach some code for `User` class definition please

Comment: @Alex it's added

Comment: Looks like your query returns `Etablissement` but not `User`. You should change query or return type

Answer (score 0):

Clarify few things:

1. The MYSQL PHPmyAdmin you have queried on and the service you are connecting database to are pointing to the same database server?
2. Have you checked manually if 'id' column is created in the tables you are querying to?

Comment: Checked in Etablissement for id?

Comment: Try making simple query for your debugging purpose first... like "SELECT * FROM app_user" and also "SELECT * FROM etablissement" from your Query Repository (with @Query) and call them simply from Rest controller.. check whether you face any issue related to 'id' in these queries?

Comment: you have conflict  when join query you have tow id  here etablissement and app_user and same has the same name id

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query if you have `create_time` field in `User` entity

```
@Query(value="SELECT u from User u where year(u.creatdate_time)=:year")
public List<User> findALLUserByyear(@Param("year") String year);
```